# scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(x,y) not working to calculate distance

Tags: python, coordinates, euclidean-distance

I have a program that is going to generate (nEls number of) line segments - but I do not want the line segments to overlap.

To do this, I am generating co-ordinates randomly, and checking if each co-ordinate is at a minimum distance apart from previously generated co-ordinates.

```
from psychopy import visual
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random, randint, normal, shuffle
import scipy.spatial.distance

nEls = 500
minDist = 25
i=1

coordX = [0] 
coordY = [0]


while i < nEls:
    too_close=1 #defining proximity boundary between each line stimulus of given value when plotting  
    while too_close==1:
        x = (random()*465)-232.5 #generating randomised x values
        y = (random()*465)-232.5 #generating randomised y values
        too_close=0

        for j in range(i):
            dist = scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(x,y)
            if (dist<minDist):
                too_close=1
    coordX.append(x)
    coordY.append(y)
    i += 1

xy = np.concatenate((coordX, coordY))
xys = np.reshape(xy, (-1,2))

win = visual.Window(size=(832,624))


antialias = 1.0/4

line_length = 10

maskSize = int(1/antialias)
mask = np.zeros([maskSize, maskSize])
mask[:, 1:-1] = 1
tex = None
sizes=[2,line_length]
sfs = 0 # makes no sense when texture absent
oris = 20

elements = visual.ElementArrayStim(win, nElements=nEls,
                                sizes=sizes, sfs=sfs, units='pix',
                                elementTex=tex, elementMask=mask,
                                fieldShape='sqr')                              

elements.setXYs(xys)
elements.setOris(oris)

for frameN in range(100):
    elements.draw()
    win.flip()
```

The code above does not produce any error messages, but the line segments are not being placed according to the minimum distance (from inspection of the image).

To double check the distance of each of those co-ordinates, I used the following codes:

```
check = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(xys)
print check
```

The resulting response shows that the distance between each co-ordinate is occasionally below the minimum distance.

Thank you.

P.S. I have tried using smaller `nEls` values, and the problem is still there, so I don’t think it has anything to do with the region being too small.